# Drawing a line of best fit in a log-log plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have graphed two matrices on a log-log plot and I determined the slope of the line of best fit with the following:

```
loglog(x,y);
polyfit(log(width_matrix),log(error_matrix),1)
```

Is it possible to draw the line of best fit on the same log-log plot and perhaps include its equation on the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
figure; hold on;
loglog(x, y, '.');
% fit in log domain
p = polyfit(log(x), log(y), 1);
% compute fit in linear domain
y_hat = exp(p(1) * log(x) + p(2));
% make log log plot
loglog(x, y_hat);

label = ['log(y) = ' num2str(p(1)) 'log(x) + ' num2str(p(2))];
legend('data', label);
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I specify the attributes of the line and also tell it to hold on. For example I receive an error if I specify cross marks and tell it to hold on with 'x.' and 'x','.'.

Comment: Never mind, used an alternative method. I am going to answer it below if you want to see what i did. Thanks so much though!

Answer (score 1):

```
p = polyfit(log(x), log(y),1);
y_hat=exp(p(1)*log(width_matrix)+p(2));
loglog(x,y_hat,'--or',x,y,'+');

label = ['log(y) = ' num2str(p(1)) 'log(x) + ' num2str(p(2))];
legend('data', label);
```

Shout out to @prgao for answering the question. I realized the loglog function can take multiple inputs so you can add in all the components you would like to graph on the same plot and even specify the attributes. I'm sure you could do the same with @prgao's answer but I was having difficulty.