# Multiple plots on a logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot two lines (data and linear fit) in a single graph with logarithmic scale. My code:

```
Iots = I_An./Temp.^2;  % I Over T Squared
Oot = 1./Temp; % One Over T
[p,~] = polyfit(Oot,Iots,1);
linfit = polyval(p,Oot);

figure('color','w','units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
hold on
loglog(Oot,Iots,'.','LineWidth',2);
loglog(Oot,linfit,':r','LineWidth',2);
```

The result is not a logarithmic scale graph:

[image: the graph im getting]

If I run just one of the plot lines, it works on its own. What should I do? Are there any contradicting commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call `hold on` *after* creating your first `loglog` plot. Also, you only need to use `loglog` on the first plot to create the logarithmic axes. After than you can just call normal `plot` and it will use the logarithmic axes.

```
x = linspace(0, 100);

loglog(x, x, '.', 'LineWidth', 2);

hold on
plot(x, x.^2, '.r', 'LineWidth',2);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The graph is now in logarithmic scale.

Comment: But I have a followup question - how do I make the fit linear in this scale?

Comment: @ScubaDiving If you want a linear fit to logarithmic data, you'll want to plot on a linear scale and just compute the `log` of your data prior to plotting and plot that.

Comment: But I need them on the same graph, meaning in logarithmic scale... I'm not sure I got you.

Comment: When you say fit are you referring to the built-in curve fit or what are you referring to?

Comment: In the code I attached these two lines generate a vector of points in a linear fit corresponding with the x-axis vector (in this case, Oot):
    `[p,~] = polyfit(Oot,Iots,1);
    linfit = polyval(p,Oot);`

Comment: @ScubaDiving You should just be able to use `plot(Oot, linfit)`

Comment: @ScubaDiving You are plotting a line on a logarithmic scale so that looks as expected. Are you trying to fit a line to the *logarithm* transformation of your data instead (the one you see?)?

Comment: I see the problem. The data is linear in _logarithmic_ scale, so I need to create the fit so it will be linear in _logarithmic_ scale too - I didn't do it right. How do I do it?

Comment: @ScubaDiving So you should either fit a line to the logarithmic transform of your data `polyfit(log(Oot), log(Iots), 1)` or you should use a log fit rather than a linear fit.

Comment: I tried doing that, both with `linfit = polyval(p,Oot)` and with `linfit = polyval(p,log(Oot))`, but this doesn't work...

Comment: I mean that I can't see it, probably because it isn't fitting correctly... [link]http://i.imgur.com/arSnmMj.png

Comment: @ScubaDiving This is beyond the scope of this question but it looks like there are some similar questions that may help you out such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236857/drawing-a-line-of-best-fit-in-a-log-log-plot

Comment: You are right, I should've looked for this as a seperate question. The link you proved helped me a lot - it worked! Thanks a lot.